# Advice on a simple SQL select

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, ado.net

I'm looking on some feedback on a basic SQL script, is the "in (select)" the most efficient way of doing this? Or am i looking to over complicate something that doesn't need to be.

```
SELECT emailAddress FROM user where companyId in (SELECT id FROM company WHERE trialist = 1 AND DATEADD(DAY,-14,TrialEndDate) = '2020-08-13 00:00:00');
```

This script will be run from a .Net Framework console app using Dapper.

Comment: Your query is more or less already optimal.  The next step might be to tune the subquery to run faster by using indices.  Have you looked into that yet?

Comment: You should refactor this part: `DATEADD(DAY,-14,TrialEndDate) = '2020-08-13 00:00:00'`, you are forcing the calculation on every single row, and this means any index on `TrialEndDate` can't be used, this would be better written as `TrialEndDate = DATEADD(DAY, 14, '2020-08-13 00:00:00')`, now you only have to do the `DATEADD` calculation once, and you can use any indexes on `TrialEndDate`

Comment: To answer your actual question though `IN (SELECT ...)` is fine. Some would argue `EXISTS ()` is semantically a better fit, but almost every optimiser I know of comes up with the same plan for both anyway. (e.g. SQL Server: [IN vs. JOIN vs. EXISTS](https://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/)) so really it is personal preference. I prefer `EXISTS` for the sole reason that I have accidentally selected an outer column inside the `IN` before, and ended up with unexpected results

Comment: Thanks for those answers, that answers my question and that article looks very informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming no duplicates in the `company` table (which seems very reasonable given the naming conventions in the tables), I would recommend:

```
SELECT u.emailAddress 
FROM user u JOIN
     company c
     ON u.companyId = c.id 
WHERE c.trialist = 1 AND
      c.TrialEndDate = DATEADD(day, 14, '2020-08-13');
```

Why do I recommend this?  Two reasons.

The first is that an explicit `JOIN` gives the optimizer more choices on optimization.  That can be a big win if one method is faster than another.

Second, the `DATEADD()` function makes the job of the optimizer *much* harder (almost any function has this effect).  It precludes the use of an index on the column; it prevents the optimizer from partition pruning (if the table is partitioned on that column); it obfuscates statistics collected about the column.  Moving the function to a constant eliminates all these issues.

Then, if you want to optimize the query, you would add an index on `company(trialist, trialenddate)` and on `user(companyid)`.